# Why the indefinite article is not used before institutions when we think of the general idea of these places?

Tags: indefinite-article, zero-article

I don't understand why the indefinite article is not used before **institutions** (prison, hospital, university, college, church, etc.) when we think of the general idea of these places and what they are used for.

For example:

> My brother is sick in hospital.

Or:

> Michelle is a student at art school.

Is it an exception that I have to memorize?

Comment: They do use a definite article before 'hospital' in America, even when no specific hospital is being considered.

Comment: You just need to bear the usage *in mind*.  If you're not referring to a specific hospital, or to a specific mind, it's uncountable. You might think of preposition + zero-article + noun of place  as a locative adverbial phrase.

Comment: OK, Michael. I see. My question was about **indefinite** article. ) And I'm trying to revise British English.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thank you, now I have to find out what is "adverbial phrase" in my native language. )

Comment: "In hospital" is a fixed expression. Syntactically, it's a 'bare' noun phrase functioning as complement of "is". Internally, "hospital" is complement of the prep "in". In this context a determiner would not be permitted.

Comment: It became a fixed expression for a reason. To say that something is a complement of **is** is vacuous, in the archaic sense. It is not lacking in intelligence but in content.  The complement of **is** is predicated of the subject. What is the nature of that predication?

Comment: It's not a dependent of "sick", so what else could it possibly be? It's a locative complement of "is", though not predicative.

Comment: Predicative (and locative) complements refer to a predicand of course, but they are complements (i.e. arguments) of the verb, not the subject.

Comment: How does any of that address the question of the zero-article?

Comment: You raised the topic, not me. I gave a clear answer that as a bare NP, it does not need a determiner.

Comment: OP is asking *why* it is bare there.

Comment: I'm aware of that.

Comment: In the OP's example, the noun "hospital" acts as an indication of the associated activity and does not have its standard denotation, e.g. "There are two hospitals in the county". This probably accounts for the fact that a determiner is not used.

Comment: @BillJ: "In this context, a determiner would not be permitted." -- Then why, pray tell, do millions of American say "in THE hospital" (and actually never say "in hospital). Is it just permitted in the US?

Answer (score 1):

It would be perfectly grammatical, I believe, even in BrE (I speak AmE), to say

> I just know he is lying in **a** hospital somewhere. He doesn't know how to control that motorcycle very well yet.

The reference there is to an unknown but particular hospital, but God knows where.

In BrE, when you're referring to his *locative status* (he is "hospitalized"), and not to a specific hospital, you do not use an article:

> He's laid up in hospital.

In AmE, when referring to no hospital in particular, but to the status "hospitalized", instead of using the zero article you would use the definite article:

> He's laid up in the hospital.

We use the definite article to refer to the place in general terms, to say that he has been hospitalized.

Comment: I need some time to think about your first example, because I can't understand it and unfortunately I have no time for that now. I will be back as soon as I have it. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "particular hospital" in your explanation to the first example? Did you mean someone (for example, some friend of both speakers) knows it, but not the speakers? But they are aware of that (of the fact that their friend knows that hospital)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to "God knows where". In that case could I ask you to explain what do you mean by "an unknown but particular hospital"?

Comment: @Anna Sevastyanova: The reference is to a place, not to a status. The speaker is imagining the motorcyclist lying injured in a bed in a hospital somewhere, an actual place.  The speaker is not saying that the motorcyclist has been "hospitalized", which is a status. Compare *The lawyer is **in court** today*. That refers to the lawyer's status, not to a particular location.

Comment: I believe that the omission or inclusion of the article with certain institutions is a matter of learning them individually according to the dialect you're learning. But I also believe that the use of the definite article with post office, library, hospital, bank, for instance, stems from a time when every town/city had one of each. Again, that's a personal hypothesis, but, I think, a valid one.

Comment: @CocoPop: Here I'm describing the zero-article usage .  The use of the definite article is not unrelated but it's a separate question.  When we express *status* we don't use the article: *She is in labor.  The lawyer is in court today.   Court is in session.  He is in jeopardy.  The success of the entire mission is in doubt.  The account is in arrears. The salt is now in suspension. The audience was in shock.*

Comment: @CocoPop I was interested why is it mentioned in my grammar book that we do not use **"the"** with institutions when we are thinking of the general idea of these places and what they are used for and there is nothing about **"a"**. Just examples with zero article. That is why I asked the question about the indefinite article. That is exactly what I wanted to know, why we also don't use "a" in this case. I suppose it's just a rule. And I'm sorry, Tᴚoɯɐuo, I can't understand the difference between a person lying in hospital and a hospitalized person.

Comment: @CocoPop Sorry, have to go now. I won't be available until Monday evening (UTC +3).

Comment: @AnnaSevastyanova: I'm sure you  understand the difference between *location* and *status*.